# How to draw Circular Progress by image in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm facing a hard problem. I want to create a Circular progress by using image. You can see the follow image here : [image: http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/3782/o27w.png] .

I don't know how to draw it. Could you please give me some advice for drawing. There is a library to do that? I searched on the internet, I found that all library using color, not use image. Please help me. Thanks so much.

Comment: https://github.com/danielamitay/DACircularProgress. You could try to tweak it to get the look right.

Comment: @CaptJak - at the very least the code provides a the OP a great starting point.

Comment: @CaptJak: Thanks, I read it but it only using color not image. Another suggestion?

Comment: @Adam: Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: Why do you want to use an image? What benefit? How about drawing the progress into a context and rendering into an image?

Comment: @user3114750 - Your image of a loader is a prototype. Build the "image" using code (`CALayer`'s) and use the `DACircularProgress` code as a starting point to figure out how.

Comment: @Adam: Could you please give me some code? I'm really thankful.

Comment: @user3114750 - sure. Here's some great stuff to help you start: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html and https://github.com/danielamitay/DACircularProgress

Comment: @Adam: Is there any more solutions?

Comment: If you are asking him to do it for you, I don't think he will. Start with the link I gave and work it out. Once you have it down, post it as an answer for your own question.